# Can I include 64-bit DLLs in a Unity 5 project?

Tags: unity, dll

I am building a C# DLL for inclusion in a Unity project. Due to some dependencies, this must be a 64-bit DLL. The last time I checked, DLLs for Unity had to be built with .NET Framework 3.5 [(although this isn't explicitly stated in the DLL documentation)](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html). Are there any requirements for bitness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the 64-bit version of the Editor then you need a 64-bit plugin and vice versa. If you are using the 64-bit editor but are also targeting 32-bit platforms you will need two versions of the dll.

Here is a [related discussion](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/265929/32bit-and-64-bit-plugin-environment.html) that may be helpful to make it more clear.

Here is [another discussion](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/using-plugins-for-x86-and-x86_64-architectures-issue-with-sqlite3-dll-in-beta-9-solved.276719/), that explains how to import and configure both plugins side-by-side.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you should be able to. However, it might limit you to a x64 build.